# Finding the indexes for which the pattern matches in a 2D list in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
Given a 2D list:  
Data = [  
[1, 2, 3],   
[1, 2, 3],   
[1, 1, 3],   
[1, 0, 3]  
]

Input Pattern:
test = [1,*,3]

Expected Result:
[0,1,2,3]

Another example:  
Input Pattern: [1,2,*]  

Expected result: [0,1]
```

Problem definition: I have a 2D list, and the input consists of a given pattern and the info on which cols to search for matching the elements, whereas the values in the remaining cols can be ignored.

More on problem, I have got a 2D list with 'm' columns and certain no of rows as observation. Input is a list(Observation) of size 1*n where n < m, I am supposed to find out the indexes of the observations which matches the given input observation.

Possible solution: if only first and second column are to looked then 
let 'V' all the possible values  in the third column then

This is following example I done:

```
   from itertools import izip as zip, count  

    a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 3], [1, 0, 3],[1,2,0]]
    index = []
    test = [1,2]
    V = [0,1,3]
    print a
    for v in V:
         test.append(v)
         print test

         indexes = [i for i, j in zip(count(), a) if j == test]
         index.append(indexes)
         test.pop()
    print index
```

Is it the best way? I believe there will be much more efficient way to do this

Comment: Could you rephrase the possible solution, I dont understand what your saying there